# Translation not refreshing for Primeng fileupload error message in Angular

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have applied language translation for Primeng file upload error message `invalidFileTypeMessageDetail`. 
The selected language is shown in the error message either in English or French.

While switching from English to French or from French to English, the text is not updated, but other data is updated like the `chooseLabel` button and content.

```
<p-fileUpload [chooseLabel]="chooseLabel" invalidFileTypeMessageSummary="{0} : {{'global.form.invalidFileType' | translate}},"></p-fileUpload>
```